# Offline r-base installation on SLES12.3

Tags: r, installation, offline, suse

We need to install `R-base version 3.5+` on an **offline** machine running `SLES12.3`

We have downloaded **all** the packages from the the SUSE r repo
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/released/openSUSE_12.3/x86_64/

while running `zypper  install` on the packages there are additional dependencies that we are not able to find the relevant packages to download.
These include:

```
libtcl8.5.so()(64bit)
libgomp.so.l()(64bit)
```

But we are not able to find the dependency package that include these libraries.

1. What should be the correct approach for installing these libraries offline? where can we find these libraries?
2. Is there a better way for offline installing `R-base` ? we tried to follow the instructions on the [cran rstudio page](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/suse/)

Comment: Installing R itself would meet your needs ?

Comment: Yes R version 3.5

Answer (score 1):

The files you downloaded don't match the distribution you're running. SUSE Linux Enterprise (SLE) and openSUSE are similar in some ways, but these are really two separate distributions and you can not always mix binaries between the two. To install R on SLE Server 12.3, you should use the repository https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/released/SLE_12/.

You can find out these URLs by looking at the right hand-side column at https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/devel:languages:R:released. Look for things called "SLE" there.

Comment: I used this link http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/released/SLE_12/x86_64/ and still got the error about `libtcl8.5.so()(64bit)`

Answer (score 0):

Install the Development Tools, according to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/439185)

`zypper install --type pattern Basis-Devel`

Download R source and install it

```
wget http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz
tar zxf R-3.5.0.tar.gz
cd R-3.5.0
./configure --enable-R-shlib
make
make check
make install
```

Maybe there are still dependencies missing, which need to be installed with zypper (I don't have any Suse to try myself). With this method you have an "empty" R and you will install R packages one by one (with `R CMD INSTALL`). Maybe not the best answer for your need, but an answer.

Comment: I think the missing libraries are not from R but rather from OS

Comment: I think so, but you'll find out what is missing during the compilation step. Maybe installing the Development Tools is enough to unblock your installation with R-base zypper method.

Comment: I installed all the packages from `Basis-Devel` but still getting the same error.